# Registring CustomPropertyEditors for using in BeanWrapper

Tags: spring-boot, spring-java-config, spring-bean

I am trying to register custom property editors using the following configuration in my spring boot application.Reffered the following documentation [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch05s04.html) section 5.4.2.1.

```
@Bean
 public static CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
    CustomEditorConfigurer configurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    configurer.setPropertyEditorRegistrars(new PropertyEditorRegistrar[] {
                (registry) -> registry.registerCustomEditor(Instant.class,    new CustomInstantEditor()) });
        return configurer;
    }
```

When I created a BeanWrapper and using it I am getting the following error

Code:

```
BeanWrapper newAccountWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(newAccount);
newAccountWrapper.setPropertyValue("chardate", value);
```

Error is:

```
Exception is Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.Instant] for property 'chardate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.Instant] for property 'chardate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

But the above code works if I register the CustomEditor for the BeanWrapper

```
BeanWrapper newAccountWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(newAccount);
newAccountWrapper.registerCustomEditor(Instant.class, new
             CustomInstantEditor());
```

So can I not register customPropertyEditors using CustomEditorConfigurer BeanFactoryPostProcessor ?

Additional Info:

```
    BeanWrapper newAccountWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(newAccount);
    newAccountWrapper.registerCustomEditor(Instant.class, new CustomInstantEditor());
    newAccountWrapper.registerCustomEditor(Money.class, new CustomMoneyEditor());

    newAccountWrapper.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);

    accountDomainElements.forEach((accountElement, value) -> {
        newAccountWrapper.setPropertyValue(accountElement, value);
```

Comment: Not if you are creating the `BeanWrapper` yourself and not apply the configures to it. When Spring creates an instance it will detect all configurers and apply those to the created `BeanWrapper` implementation. You aren't doing that and basically are bypassing Spring in this. Why are you creating your own instance any way?

Comment: So if I create a BeanWrapper I should configure it explicitly  and CustomEditorConfigurer will not help

Comment: No when the Spring MVC stuff creates a `BeanWrapper` instance it does some additional configuration. It will set the `ConversionService` and use registered `PropertyEditorRegistrar` instances to add additional `PropertyEditors`. However as you are creating the instances yourself you totally bypass this option. Why do you even need to create your own instance of the `BeanWrapper` that is generally something you don't do yourself.

Comment: I want to get some properties of a bean as well as set some properties of beans , using the property names. So I thought I can use bean Wrapper

Comment: Added additionalInfo showing the code I written using BeanWrapper

Comment: Why not simply use the getter and setters? Why the complexity with the bean wrapper?

Comment: I only know the PropertyNames  that I need to access in Map and the map changes so thought of using BeanWrapper which can be used to get the properties in a bean using PropertyNames.

Comment: And how are you obtaining this map?

Comment: actually this is Rest API and I am getting the propertyNames in the JSON request as a map.

Comment: Then why are you doing it yourself? Let Spring do it for you... Just add a method argument of the type you need and annotate with `@RequestBody`... Spring will take care of converting tje JSON from/to the required object...

Comment: The JSON that I get is not actual representation of the object but its some generic message with a map containing some key value pairs. these key value pairs represent some of the elements in the actual object

Answer (score 0):

Give a try

```
@Bean
public CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
    CustomEditorConfigurer configurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    Map<Class<?>, Class<? extends PropertyEditor>> customEditors = new HashMap<>();
    customEditors.put(Instant.class, CustomInstantEditor.class);
    configurer.setCustomEditors(customEditors);
    return configurer;
}
```